# “guiWidgetsToolkittcltk” is not a defined class

Tags: r, gwidgets

I want to create GUI using gWidget in R but I am getting all these kind of weird errors:

```
guitoolkit = new("guiWidgetsToolkittcltk")
Error in getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())) : 
  “guiWidgetsToolkittcltk” is not a defined class
```

or:

```
> setIs("guiWidget","guiWidgetORgWidgetTcltkORtcltk")
Error in .walkClassGraph(classDef, "subclasses", where) : 
  the 'subClass' list for class “guiWidgetORgWidgetTcltkORtcltk”, includes an undefined class “guiWidget”
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: The first one works for me. Not the second one. What is your version of `gWidgets`?

Comment: I just installed gWidgets in RStudio. Not sure how I can find its version

Comment: `sessionInfo()` will give you the version of all the packages you have loaded.

Comment: gWidgetsRGtk2_0.0-83 and gWidgets_0.0-54

Comment: Does this happen at the console? (Though either way, I'd suggest you look at `gWidgets2` to see if it happens there. Any new projects should start there.)